# Remove [tiled]->[tiles] tag synonym

Tags: discussion

"tiled" often refers to the [open source map editor](http://www.mapeditor.org) software and format, which enjoys wide support across many languages and game frameworks. However, [tiled](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiled) is currently a synonym for the very general [tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiles).

A [search for the exact term "tiled"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tiled%22) shows many results, about half of which are about the specific editor/format. Therefore I believe this synonym should be removed, and recreated as its own tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch! This was a very old synonym - it has now been removed.